# What do kids(6-15) need to know in Math to be able to understand Math easily and effectively?

Tags: primary-education, india

I teach kids in a village and I was wondering if there is a list of Facts, Procedures, things, a kid 6-15 years of age should know to be able to easily understand things at his/her level of Math. Basics like What are Numbers? Operations etc.

Comment: Which country is the village in? A lot of countries have curriculums that specify such issues.

Comment: India. Yes curriculum specifies that but I was trying to tap into vast experience of Teachers here to highlight things that are not obvious or specified but very important...

Comment: What they need to know is determined by the curriculum. For ideas how to get them there (the youngest ones in particular) look at [this](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/750/282).

Comment: Do you have any response to my answer?

Comment: @user21820 Your answer is for little older kids (youngest 9) as you have mentioned. I work mostly with younger kids like 5-6-7 years. Logic is essential, but too advanced for young kids. Can't articulate exactly what I am looking for but let me try, somehow I think a+b=? and a-?=c type questions for primary kids have real and direct relation with x+y=c linear equation. So how do I teach addition and subtraction such that, what is required to make sense of linear equations gets built automatically. Similarly what is the common set that I build so that kids easily understand higher Math.

Comment: @AshishShukla: I think your approach is backwards. It's better to cultivate a curious mindset aiming to discover truths, rather than to attempt to achieve specific goals that are boring, such as "linear equations". Do take a look at the examples I stated in my second post. Pascal's triangle for example is accessible to 7 yr olds. Just play with the stuff, and don't try to force it to go somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I have written before about [what should be taught at the high-school level](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/16705/1550), and anyone who knows basic logic as described there will "*be able to easily understand things at his/her level of Math*" and beyond to every area of mathematics in the future as well. Besides that, you should also let students (especially but not just children) [explore concrete interesting mathematics](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/18990/1550).

I think it cannot be denied that attempting to teach or do mathematics without a solid foundation of basic logic is just like writing software by copy-pasting from StackOverflow. So basic logic has to be taught well. On the other hand, you need to motivate learning the basics, and that is what the games, puzzles and other recreational mathematics are for.